# c# saving settings while reading settings

Tags: c#, exception, application-settings, file-read, file-writing

I have a method which save settings to file. This method is called if value of dateTimePicker changed. But I have in Form_Load loading settings -> I read value from file and assign it with dateTimePicker, but this call method save_settings (couse value changed). And in this moment is problem couse the file is open by program -> reading values and program wanna write to file changes...
How can I do that?

Comment: Would need to see the code that you currently have in order to help correct your problem.. please copy paste in the code where you are having this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have critical section. There are plenty ways  to deal with this issue . One way is to put  Lock statement around file saving .  This way one thread should wait after another thread is finished. But from understanding your question I think that problem is with your desing . As I understand you trying to read and write simultaneously . Maybe you should declare global bool variable isToSave . That will indicate when you can save . When working with file do not forget to use using statement to release file
Handle.

Comment: I used checking by variable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of flag - set it when you start reading your config and unset it in `finally` block. When the flag is set, ignore calls to `ValueChanged`. Since you are loading config in `OnLoad`, there will be no other reasons for dateTimePicker's value change because you're in main UI thread and message pump is not pumping at the moment.

Comment: Also Free / destroy your StreamReader / StreamWriter objects when done.v reference @ Gregory's answer